# "Fluids" versus "liquids"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

What is the difference between *fluid* and *liquid*?

I'm thinking of this in the context of *drink plenty of fluids*.

Comment: [Some interesting answers here](http://www.englishforums.com/English/LiquidVsFluid/dwnrb/post.htm)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A fluid can either be a liquid or a gas; as such, *fluid* is a hypernym of *liquid* in this regard. In your example

> Drink plenty of fluids

it's only idiomatic to use *fluids* instead of *liquids*. (I wonder what else could be drunk besides a liquid/fluid, anyway!) You also hear things like:

> Your body needs lots of fluids

In day-to-day usage, one will find *liquid* only used when the state of matter of a substance is in question or important to note. For example:

> "How's the brownie mix looking?" "It's still basically liquid!"

When ice-cream is involved, *melted* is more likely to be used instead of *liquid*. One may also find *liquid* used in a financial context:

> They think I'm liquid but, man, I'm flat broke!

*Fluid* just sounds smoother and it rolls off the tongue much easier. That probably explains why it's more commonly used in place of *liquid*. People would probably use *gas* if they wanted to be specific. Here are some common idiomatic phrases:

- *body fluids*
- *engine fluid*
- *transmission fluid*
- *poisonous liquid*
- *hot liquid*
- *toxic fluid[s]*
- *liquid coolant*
- *cooling fluid*

From the above examples, you may notice that *fluid* tends to be used for a liquid substance that has a specified/particular purpose. Thus, *transmission liquid* would be unidiomatic, for instance.

Comment: A fluid can even be a powder if it is fine enough to be thought of as something that flows like a liquid would for the purposes under discussion.

Answer (score 9):

A [liquid](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/liquid) is a state of matter in which the molecules move freely but tend not to separate; e.g. water at room temperature. A [fluid](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fluid) is simply something that flows, be it gas, or liquid.

Answer (score 7):

*Fluid* describes a substance that has no fixed shape and changes shape freely based on outside influences. It can describe two states of matter: *gas* and *liquid*. To think of it another way, a liquid is a fluid, but a fluid is not necessarily a liquid.

Answer (score 5):

In general usage, "liquid" and "fluid" are synonyms.

In a scientific context they are not.

"Liquid" is a state of matter: solid, liquid, gas, plasma, Bose-Einstein condensate

"Fluid" describes certain properties generally attributed to substances in a liquid state

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid)

> Fluids display such properties as:
>       * not resisting deformation, or resisting it only lightly (viscosity), and
>       * the ability to flow (also described as the ability to take on the shape of the container).

The degree of fluidity depends on the substance and the prevailing conditions (e.g. temperature and pressure).

Consider water, motor oil and maple syrup. At room temperature, they are all liquids. As the temperature drops, all three liquids get denser and flow more slowly.

At 32° F / 0° C water becomes a solid (ice) and no longer flows. Motor oil and maple syrup continue to flow, but the syrup flows more slowly.

In general usage it has become "less fluid".

Answer (score 4):

As a noun, Merriam-Webster's explicitly defines [liquid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liquid) as "a fluid."

> a fluid (as water) that has no independent shape but has a definite volume and does not expand indefinitely and that is only slightly compressible

Unless you are writing in a scientific or explicitly academic context, I'd say the two are interchangeable. Note that as adjectives, they do have slightly different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

liquid: existing as or having characteristics of a liquid; especially tending to flow

fluid: subject to change; variable

Additionally, liquid is a state of matter. Not all liquids can be consumed.

Answer (score 1):

A fluid is anything  that flows. so naturally it includes both liquids and gases.
thus it is clear that all liquids are fluids but not all fluids are liquids, as fluid also contain substances in gaseous state. but also fluid is a subset of matter So, the difference between liquids and fluids boils down to their viscosity as fluids have a higher viscosity such as oils than liquids. Fluids can be gases also whereas liquids arte altogether different than gases.