# Difference between "fluid" and "liquid"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, vocabulary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Fluids” versus “liquids”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7329/fluids-versus-liquids)

What is the difference between *fluid* and *liquid*?